# ArrayList gives only last elements outside nested loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I m reading a csv file that contains 4 columns and 150 data. At first I read each line into string array and convert it into integer array. then i converted it into arraylist. IF i try to display my arraylist outside while loop it only displays the last array entries. After completing while loop I want all values in arraylist and pass it to another function. How can I achieve this target?

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.*;


public class ReadInputCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/sana/Desktop/DATASET/shuttle.csv"));

        String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 
        while (dataRow != null){
        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(","); 
        int[] intsArray=new int[dataArray.length]; 
        for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
        {
                    intsArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i]);                
        }

       intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(intsArray.length);

       for (int i=0; i<intsArray.length; i++)
       {
                    intList.add(intsArray[i]);
       }

      dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();               

       }
        CSVFile.close();
    } 

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to print your list or pass it to another method? I don't see an attempt at either.

Comment: An array list only makes sense to store a single row of data.  How do you plan on passing all data to the method?  Also, you never loop over your file.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of your while loop you have a:

```
intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(intsArray.length);
```

And after this instruction you add datas in your intList. It is therefore normal that you only see the datas coming from the last iteration, since a new instance of an ArrayList is associated to your intList variable at each iteration.

Also you can combine:

```
String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 
   while (dataRow != null){

    //...

dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
```

into the more compact following form:

```
String dataRow = null;
while ((dataRow = CSVFile.readLine()) != null) {
   // Your loop instructions here
}
```

Applying these changes your code becomes something like:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.*;


public class ReadInputCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/sana/Desktop/DATASET/shuttle.csv"));

        String dataRow = null; 
        while ((dataRow = CSVFile.readLine()) != null){
           String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(","); 
           int[] intsArray=new int[dataArray.length]; 
           for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
           {
              intsArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i]);                
           }

           // No more instanciation of the intList here

           for (int i=0; i<intsArray.length; i++)
           {
                    intList.add(intsArray[i]);
           }

           // No more CSVFile.readLine() here               
        }
        CSVFile.close();
    } 
}
```

This should give you all the datas in your ArrayList but would have no way to know which data comes from which line. If that is not an issue for you and this should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Do not re initialize your intList within while loop.
Below Line is not required

```
intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(intsArray.length);
```